# how to count columns and rows dynamically of vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Good morning All...
i need help, how to count columns and rows of datagrid in vb.net dynamically? i have made but still statis if i add new data, result of calculation is not move to new column. i have coding which i have made..

```
    DGV2.Columns.Add("Total Km", "Total Km")
    'DGV2.Columns.Add("Percentage", "Percentage")
    Dim bykdata As Integer = DGV2.RowCount - 1
    Dim bykkolom As Integer = DGV2.ColumnCount + 1
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim d As Integer
    Dim g As Integer
    Dim f As Integer
    Dim h As Integer
    Dim i As Integer 'looping
    Dim j As Integer 'looping
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim m As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim o As Integer
    Dim v As Integer
    'Dim w As Integer
    'Dim x As Integer
    Dim tot As Integer

    'ambildata
    For i = 0 To bykdata
        v = DGV2.Item(2, i).Value
        a = DGV2.Item(3, i).Value
        b = DGV2.Item(4, i).Value
        c = DGV2.Item(5, i).Value
        d = DGV2.Item(6, i).Value
        g = DGV2.Item(7, i).Value
        f = DGV2.Item(8, i).Value
        h = DGV2.Item(9, i).Value
        k = DGV2.Item(10, i).Value
        m = DGV2.Item(11, i).Value
        n = DGV2.Item(12, i).Value
        o = DGV2.Item(13, i).Value
        c = v + a + b + c + d + g + f + h + k + m + n + o
        DGV2.Item(14, i).Value = c.ToString
    Next

    For j = 0 To bykdata
        a = DGV2.Item(3, j).Value
        tot = tot + a
        DGV2.Item(15, j).Value = tot.ToString
    Next
```

Comment: Wow!! What a code!! Why the need of so many variables!

Answer (score 0):

Your variable names are not very descriptive, it's hard to understand what you are doing. But here's a quick way I could.

```
Dim total As Integer = 0

For i = 0 To bykdata
    Dim rowSum As Integer = 0

    For columnIndex = 2 To 13
        rowSum += DGV2.Item(columnIndex, i).Value
    Next

    total += DGV2.Item(3, j).Value

    DGV2.Item(14, i).Value = rowSum.ToString
    DGV2.Item(15, j).Value = total.ToString
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

for column sum at bottom you can use this. You have to add a row

```
DGV2.Rows(DGV2.RowCount - 1).Cells("Total Km").Value = Convert.ToDouble(CType(DGV2.DataSource, DataTable).Compute("SUM(Total Km)", ""))
```

for horizontal cell sum you have to loop like this and you have to add a column total just like you did

```
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DGV2.Rows
            For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                    If Not cell.Value Is DBNull.Value Then
                        sum1 += cell.Value
                    End If
            Next
            row.Cells("Total KM").Value = sum1
            sum1 = Nothing
        Next
```